# How do i get nginx to serve assets adjacent to index.html when using proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, github-pages

How do i get nginx to serve assets adjacent to index.html when using proxy_pass?

Context: I have a github repository that serves up content using github pages. When serving from a repository, GHP requires a url path that matches the repository name

`rightisleft.github.io/repo_name/`

Currently `index.html` and all subdirectories are working as expected. Loading assets from `(css/*, images/*)` return 200s.

However, assets like `robots.txt` and other files in the repository root return 404s.

Here's my domain .conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.redacted.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host rightisleft.github.io;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass https://rightisleft.github.io/redacted/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }        
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.redacted.com,redacted.com;

    include nginxconfig.io/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {
        return 301 https://www.redacted.com$request_uri;
    }
}

# subdomains redirect
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name redacted.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem;

    return 301 https://www.redacted.com$request_uri;
}
```

**EDIT**

Nginx is used for certificate management to tie together a few different micro services.

Comment: Try dynamic routing of subdomain to folder? since on github pages you are a subdomain and not a domain. Something like `server {
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+).jgithub.io$ ;
        root /var/www/site/$subdomain;
}`

Comment: @AadityaMaheshwari - i rephrased to question. The assets are all on github pages and not the nginx server.

Comment: Does the hardcoded path work? I mean, https://rightisleft.github.io/redacted/robots.txt and the other files work when accessed from nginx?

Comment: @flaixman - when accessing https://rightisleft.github.io/redacted/robots.txt - i got a 200 - when accessing through my FQDN nginx throws a 404

Comment: @JackMurphy any chance you can save us the time and provide an actual repo with robots.txt?  e.g., a minimally reproducible case?  i'm thinking this might be related to github doing some sort of a magic, maybe based on user-agent or some other headers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this as it might work (if your css/assets are in github repo pages) and you do not need to setup many redirect unless you have a lot of domains/subdomains and I have also set redacted.com to server_name:

```
    server {
            listen 80 http2;
            listen [::]:80 http2;
            listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
            listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
            server_name redacted.com www.redacted.com;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/redacted.com/fullchain.pem;

            location / {
                    proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
                    proxy_pass              https://rightisleft.github.io/redacted$request_uri;
                    proxy_buffering         off;
                    proxy_redirect          default; #or off
                    proxy_intercept_errors on;

                    # allow GitHub to pass caching headers instead of using your own
                    expires off;
            }
    }
```